# Can't make hidden part of a web page active using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to use selenium in python to extract data from AllTrails.com/us/florida/state-parks.  What I need is the recordings data.  The site looks like the picture below when you first open it, with "reviews" active.

[Webpage Visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlqZo.png)

The html code for the portion of interest is:

[webpage HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4d2Y.png)

Right now you can see in the html that 'reviews' is active (I need recordings active)

When I physically click on the "recordings" it activates recordings, but when I try to virtually "click" on it with selenium, it does not give an error, but it is not activated and subsequent parts of the code then will not work. The relevant portion of my code is below:

```
def get_trail_links (driver, trails_url):
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.get(trails_url)
    page_count = 0

#here is where i am trying to click on the "recordings" button, no error happens here.
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h3[a/@name='Recordings']").click()

    recordings = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id ='tracks']")
    while page_count < 2:
        for record in recordings:

#here is where my button won't work because the recordings is not active in the html.

            button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@title='Show more recordings']")
            button.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            page_count += 1
```

Comment: I also tried a ten second sleep timer after clicking to give it time to "load" and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code. Also you can change the number of times the button click by changing the value in the while loop.

```
import time

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= r"D:\Selenium Learning\chromedriver_win32 (2)\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.alltrails.com/us/florida/state-parks')


wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5000)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'row trail-row')]/div/div[3]")))
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'row trail-row')]/div/div[3]").click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='tracks']/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/h4")))


page_count=0
while page_count < 2:
    button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@title='Show more recordings']")
    button.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    page_count += 1
recordings = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='tracks']/div/div/div/div/div/h4")
for recording in recordings:
    print(recording.text)
```

PS: While executing please change the executable path to your local chrome driver path.

Comment: That did work, thanks so much, this is my first time working with selenium so I have a lot to learn about it!